# EditText - not able to fetch the values

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
public boolean saveTheUpdate(int position)
   {
       System.out.println("In update Save Method");
       String strOut=objEditText.getText().toString();
       if(strOut !=null && strOut.length() !=0 && arrlstCo_ordinate.size() !=0)
       {
           mapDefect.put(objEditText.getId(),strOut); 
           Log.d("Err", "Map Size :"+mapDefect.size() +"Arr List Size :"+arrlstCo_ordinate.size());
           db.updateDefectDescription(arrlstCo_ordinate, mapDefect,position);  
           Toast.makeText(FragmentActivity.this, "Defect updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           count=1;
           removeLocalView();
           fechCoordinate();
           addViewEditText();
           return true;
       }else
       {
           Toast.makeText(FragmentActivity.this, "Please log the defect before saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
           return false;
       }     
   }
```

So, I have an EditText open. The data inside this is stored in SortedMap - mapDefect. This is used later to insert in a database. However, at random times `String strOut=objEditText.getText().toString();` is not working.

There are actually many EditTexts. It fetches information from the wrong EditText even though they have been invisible. The data is to be picked from the EditText that is currenytly visble. It works fine sometimes and sometimes it doesn't -  It fetches form the correct EditText sometimes and sometimes not.

Comment: Have you initialized the edittext by the id.

Comment: wrong in logic.even though some views are not visible that down't mean you cant use their values.

Comment: please update your question with this into: 1)what is `position` in `saveTheUpdate(int position)` | 2) how do you set `objEditText`?

Comment: @ricintech: Yes that has been done. I mentioned, sometimes I am able to fetch the values and sometimes not.
There are many EditTexts, the 1st or the 2nd EditText's value is what I am unable to fetch. The rest of the box when needed, I am able to fetch.

Comment: @Android Killer: How do I ensure to pick the values only from the visible EditText?

Comment: @ariefbayu: The value of position variable is irrelavent to the question. But it is just a ListItem's position clicked, that is passed from the calling function.
And I have already set the objEditText variable in the code. What did you mean how?

Comment: **And I have already set the objEditText variable in the code** where? I don't see it in your question. **How do I ensure to pick the values only from the visible EditText?** >> How do you add the EditText into layout?

Comment: did you checked the usual way of getting entered data in the EditText. ?if that works for you this should work ..

Comment: @ariefbayu Ok that has been elsewhere in someother activity. And the ids to the EdtiTexts are given dynamically. So upon clicking a button kind of a thing, the EditText opens.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!strOut.equalsIgnoreCase("")&& strOut.length() !=0 && arrlstCo_ordinate.size() !=0)
        {

        }
```

replace with

```
  if(strOut !=null && strOut.length() >0 && arrlstCo_ordinate.size() >0)
        {

        }
```